# Show that a certain projection is rank one.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Consider the following fragment from Murphy's "$C^*$-algebras and operator theory", namely a part of the proof of Theorem 2.4.8.

[image: ctio]

Can someone explain why $q_e$ is a rank-one projection? (see marked text). Thanks in advance.

Comment: The important part is that $q_e K(H') q_e$ is one dimensional. Suppose $q_e$ were not rank $1$, ie the image of $q_e$ contained a 2 dimensional subspace (resp $q_e=0$), can you build a two dimensional subsace of $q_e K(H')q_e$? (resp show that it is not one dimensional?)

Comment: $q_e = 0$ is impossible since $q_e = \varphi(p_e)$ and $\varphi$ has trivial kernel. But ok, suppose $q_e$ has two linearly independent vectors in its image, say $v$ and $w$. Maybe I should then do something with $F(H') \subseteq K(H')?$

Comment: Yes, suppose you build a finite rank operator out those two vectors, what happens when you conjugate with $q_e$?

Comment: Ok, let's try. Suppose that $x=q_e(v)$ and $y=q_e(w)$ are linearly independent. Define $u(x) = v, u(y) = w$ and $u(z) = 0$ for $z \notin \Bbb{C}x + \Bbb{C}y$. Then $q_e u q_e(v) = x$ and $q_e u q_e(w) = y$. Is this on the right track?

Comment: Well the way you have defined it $x=v; y=w$ but thats not a problem. Further you want $u(z)=0$ for all $z\in (\Bbb C x+\Bbb C y)^\perp$ else its not linear. Now you may write any vector of the form $a\,x+b\,y+z$ with $a,b\in\Bbb C$ and $z$ as before orthogonal to $x,y$. Then for your $u$ you can check that $q_e u q_e (a x+by+z) = u(ax+by+z)$ and you have found _one_ $u\in q_e K(H')q_e$. Can you find another one that is linearly independent to this one?

Comment: @s.harp Why is $x=v?$

Comment: Because $v$ and $w$ were chosen to be in the image of $q_e$, hence $v=q_e(\xi)$ for some $\xi$ and $q_e(v)=q_e(q_e(\xi))=q_e(\xi)=v$ and $q_e(w)=w$ in the same way.

Comment: An educated guess would be that we define the other $u'$ similarly but by $u'(v) = w$ and $u'(w) = v$ but I need to check the details.

Comment: You could also try $u'(v)=v$, $u'(w)=0$ and $u'(z)=0$ for $z$ orthogonal to $v,w$.

Comment: I'll check if that works. In the meantime you can write an answer if you like that  :)

Comment: Sure, the answer is a bit more structural but work out this example in detail, as its the main idea.

Comment: I actually have trouble showing $q_e u q_e(ax+by + z) = u(ax+by + z)$. What happens with $u(q_e(z)))?$ I guess we want $q_e(z) \in (\Bbb{C}x + \Bbb{C}y)^\perp$ right?

Comment: Yes, if $z$ is orthogonal to $x,y$ then $q_e(z)$ also is, for example $\langle x, q_e(z)\rangle = \langle q_e(x), z\rangle = \langle x, z\rangle = 0$.

Comment: I guess I have all the ingredients now to make full sense of your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V$ be a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $H$ and let $q$ be the orthogonal projection onto $V$. Then $qK(H)q= K(V)$ where $K(V)$ is embedded into $B(H)$ by extending maps to be $0$ on the orthogonal complement of $V$, this preserves compactness of the map.

By definition $q u q = u$ for all $u\in K(V)$ once you have embedded $u$ into $B(H)$, so it follows that $qK(H)q \supseteq K(V)$. This partial result already implies what is needed: If $q_e$ is not rank $1$ (and not $0$) then $\mathrm{dim}_{\Bbb C}F(\mathrm{im}(q_e))≥2$, which is in contradiction to:
$$\Bbb Cq_e=q_eK(H')q_e \supseteq K(\mathrm{im}(q_e)) \supseteq F(\mathrm{im}(q_e)).$$

For completeness the remaining direction $qK(H)q \subseteq K(V)$: If $quq\in qK(H)q$ then $quq$ is zero on the orthogonal complement of $V$ and also valued in $V$, so it is the extension by zero of a linear operator defined on $V$. The image of the closed unit ball under $quq$ is pre-compact in $H$ and also contained in the closed subspace $V$, so it is also pre-compact in $V$ and $quq$ is actually a compact operator when viewed as a map $V\to V$.